# How do I limit what kwargs will accept?

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I'm trying to write a class that will only accept some keys in kwargs and reject anything else.

This is one of the solutions I have found but I dont think it's the most efficient one, is there a better solution that I'm just missing?

```
class suvat:
    def __init__(self, **suvat):
        
        # define filter
        validKeys = ['s','u','v','a','t']
        
        # initial check to make sure all keys present
        for key in suvat.items():
            if key not in validKeys:
                raise TypeError('Invalid suvat key')
        
        # do something with keys here.
```

Comment: Just... don't accept kwargs? Use normal keyword arguments

Comment: You could make that guard code a bit shorter with some techniques, but you can't fundamentally change that you'll need to do the check yourself if you explicitly use kwargs, so Python can't enforce anything for you.

Comment: The purpose of `**kwargs` (the name following `**` is arbitrary, unrelated to any arguments it might receive) is to accept *any* keyword arguments that aren't used to set the values of other named parameters. It's not meant to be limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a known set of arguments you need to accept, use keyword only arguments

```py
def __init__(self, *, s, u, v, a, t):...
```

Make them optional

```py
def __init__(self, *, s=None, u=None, v=None, a=None, t=None):...
```

Comment: Assign a default value

Answer (score 0):

You can make this marginally more efficient as follows:

```
class Suvat:
    VALIDKEYS = set('suvat')
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        if not all(key in Suvat.VALIDKEYS for key in kwargs):
            raise TypeError('Invalid suvat key(s)', *(set(kwargs) - Suvat.VALIDKEYS))
```

However, whether you should be doing this at all is moot.

The TypeError message will also report the keywords that were used and are considered to be invalid

Answer (score 0):

As @TheMonarch said, if you want all arguments to be keyword only arguments, simply put an asterisk first. You can make them optional or required, depending on the requirements.

For a more thorough understanding, you need to understand some concepts of python arguments:

**Positional Arguments vs Keyword arguments**

Arguments can be specified according to position. They must be specified by the calling code in the same order in which they are defined by the function.

Alternatively, arguments can be specified by the caller by their name. In this case, they do not need to be specified in the order that they are defined by the function.

Keyword and positional arguments can be mixed, but the positional ones must come first, and be in the correct order.

```py
def divide(number, divide_by):
    return number / divide_by

>>> divide(10, 2)
5
>>> divide(divide_by=2, number=10)
5
```

**Required vs Optional arguments**

Any arguments that have a default value are optional. If the calling code does not provide them, the default value will be used.

```py
def divide(number, divide_by=2):
    return number / divide_by

>>> divide(10)
5
```

****kwargs**

Using the **kwargs operator, you can collect any amount of key word arguments into a dictionary.

```py
def example(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)

>>> example(apples=10, oranges=2, chocolate=100)
{'apples': 10, 'chocolate': 100, 'oranges': 2}
```

**Keyword only arguments**

The asterisk is a special value in python argument definition. Any arguments defined after an asterisk can only be supplied as keywords, and not positionally. Keyword only arguments can be required or optional, depending on whether a default value is defined.

```py
def example(a, *, b):
    return a + b

>>> example(1, 2)
...TypeError: example() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'b'
>>> example(1, b=2)
3
>>> example(a=1, b=2)
3
```